# Retrofit2 Streaming GET method OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, retrofit2

My interface:

```
public interface Downloader {
  @Streaming @GET Call<ResponseBody> get(@Url final String url);
}
```

My download method:

```
private void download(final String url, final File zip) throws IOException {
    AsyncHelper.assertNotMainThread();
    final Call<ResponseBody> call = downloaderInstance.get(url);
    final Response<ResponseBody> response = call.execute();

    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
        downloadFailed(response.code());
        return;
    }

    final ResponseBody body = response.body();
    downloadedBytes = 0;
    totalBytes = body.contentLength();

    final InputStream in;
    final OutputStream fout;

    in = body().byteStream();
    fout = new FileOutputStream(zip);

    int read;
    while ((read = in.read(BUFFER)) != -1) {
        fout.write(BUFFER, 0, read);

        downloadedBytes += read;
        LOG.d("wrote %d bytes (total: %d)", downloadedBytes, totalBytes);
    }

    body.close();
    fout.close();
}
```

This whole thing runs on a background thread and I don't get any log lines with *"wrote x bytes (total: y)"* in the log, which tells me that it's not streaming.

In a previous implementation I was running this stream directly into a `ZipInputStream` to unzip on the fly, I split the process into *download* and *decompress* steps thinking that the `ZipInputStream` might be the problem. The process fails during *download*, which means once I fix this I can revert back to unzip on the fly.

What am I doing wrong?

I've also tried `final InputStream in = response.body().source().inputStream();` with the same results. I've also tried `enqueue` instead of `execute` with the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this is embarrassing, but I'll leave it here in case others come across a similar scenario.

The answer to my question is: *"Nothing"*. I'm doing everything right. At least according to the above code.

What I *were* doing wrong though was that for debugging purposes I had logging level set to `BODY`, which means it has to put the whole thing in a buffer. That's also why no incremental progress was being reported.